# jQuery: Animating a div and button on click, but only for that instance

Tags: jquery, flexbox, jquery-animate, toggle

I'm usually pretty resourceful, but I just can't for the life of me figure this jQuery stuff out.

I'm currently working on making a somewhat interactive FAQ section on my new website. In my FAQ section, I have 2 flexbox columns, with all my Q&A "cards" in them. Each card has a Question (class=faq-question) and an Answer (class=faq-answer).

The Question will be visible and act as a toggle button and on hover-in, turns yellow, on hover-out it turns back to white, when pressed it turns gray and stays gray until it is unpressed. Also, when the Question button is pressed the hidden Answer div becomes visible and fades in smoothly, growing the flexbox vertically, revealing itself just underneath the Question. In my quest for the perfect FAQ section with all the animations and transitions, I have stumbled upon and some great jQuery demos, and took some snippets.

I've tried impleneting it for an entire day now, and I feel like it's almost there but every time I hit a Question / toggle button it acts a little weird and begins to animate all the cards! I've been scouring this site and internet all day, trying it all, but I don't usually mess with jQuery, so I'm little lost at the moment.

**ANY kind of help or different solutions would be appreciated!!**

Cheers,

*Here's my janky working version: https://codepen.io/jordan-mccready/pen/JjEVRWm*

*And here is the code:*

```
// HTML

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq-card-wrapper">
  <div class="faq-card-wrap">
    <div class="faq-card">
      <div class="faq-question">
        <h3 class="title-header is--faq">Hover me, click me</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="h-line">
      </div>
      <div class="faq-answer">
        <p class="faq-text">When clicked, hover effect is turned off.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="faq-card-wrap">
    <div class="faq-card">
      <div class="faq-question">
        <h3 class="title-header is--faq">Hover me, click me</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="h-line">
      </div>
      <div class="faq-answer">
        <p class="faq-text">When clicked, hover effect is turned off.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
// CSS

.faq-card-wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.faq-card-wrap{
  padding: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}
.faq-card {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #363534;
  color: white;
  border-radius:8px;
}
.faq-answer {
  display: none;
}
.h-line {
  height: 2px;
  background: #999;
  margin-top:-10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.title-header.is--faq {
  color: white;
  transition: ease .3s;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.title-header.is--faq:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
.title-header.is--faq.selected, .title-header.is--faq.selected.selected:hover {
  color: #999;  
}
```

```
// Feeble attempt at jQuery

$(document).ready(function() { 
   $(".faq-card .faq-question").click(function() {
    $(".title-header.is--faq").each(function() {
     $(this).toggleClass("selected");
     });
    });
    $(".faq-card .faq-question").click(function() {
      $(".faq-answer").each(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            height: "toggle",
            opacity: "toggle"
            });
         });
      });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it, or something close anyways! Here are the fixes in case anyone else ends up exactly where I was.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $(".faq-card .faq-question").click(function() {
    $(".title-header.is--faq", this).toggleClass("selected");
     });
    });
    $(".faq-question").click(function() {
      $(".faq-answer",this).slideToggle("slow"); /* kinda the same result */
         });
```

```css
.faq-card-wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.faq-card-wrap{
  padding: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}
.faq-card {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #363534;
  color: white;
  border-radius:8px;
}
.faq-answer {
  display: none;
}
.h-line {
  height: 2px;
  background: #999;
  margin-top:-10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.title-header.is--faq {
  color: white;
  transition: ease .3s;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.title-header.is--faq:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
.title-header.is--faq.selected, .title-header.is--faq.selected.selected:hover {
  color: #999;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq-card-wrapper">
  <div class="faq-card-wrap">
    <div class="faq-card">
      <div class="faq-question"> <!-- wrap this around the faq-question -->
        <h3 class="title-header is--faq">Hover me, click me</h3>
        <div class="h-line">
      </div>
      <div class="faq-answer">
        <p class="faq-text">When clicked, hover effect is turned off.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
          </div>
     <div class="faq-card-wrap">
    <div class="faq-card">
      <div class="faq-question">
        <h3 class="title-header is--faq">Hover me, click me</h3>
        <div class="h-line">
      </div>
      <div class="faq-answer">
        <p class="faq-text">When clicked, hover effect is turned off.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```